# function pointer in C++ in bisection method

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a function `my_func()`, which takes 2 parameters `a` and `b`.

I want to define a function inside the `solve_for_b_by_bisection()` function, called `f`, such that I can just call `f(b)`, which is `my_func(a, b)` for some fixed input `a`. How do I do that? Do I use a function pointer?

The reason I am doing this instead of calling `f(a,b)` directly is that in the actual thing I am working on, it has 10+ variables which are constants - it is not possible to repeat the variable list every time.

```
double my_func(const double a, const double b)
{
    /* some arbitary function */ 
}

double solve_for_b_for_contant_a_by_bisection (const double a, 
                                               const double upperbound, 
                                               const double lowerbound)
{
    double (*my_func_pointer)(const double b)
    {
        &my_func(a, b)
    }
             
    lowerboundvalue = *my_func(lowerbound)
    upperboundvalue = *my_func(upperbound)
    midpointvalue = *my_func(0.5 * (lowerbound+upperbound))
    /* The rest of the implementation */
}
```

Comment: It is called a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
auto func = [a](double b) { return my_func(a, b); };
```

Comment: what if, instead of just a, I have a list of variables?

Comment: @Lost1: You might capture more variables, either explicitly `[a]`/`[&a]`, or implicitly `[=]`/`[&]`, by value `[a]`/`[=]` or by reference `[&a]`/`[&]`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use lambda:

```
double solve_for_b_for_contant_a_by_bisection (const double a, 
                                               const double upperbound, 
                                               const double lowerbound)
{
         auto f = [a]( double b ) { return my_func( a, b ); };
         
         auto lowerboundvalue = f(lowerbound)
         auto upperboundvalue = f(upperbound)
         auto midpointvalue = f(0.5 * (lowerbound+upperbound));
         /* The rest of the implementation */
     
}
```

Comment: thanks, how do replace a with a parameter list? just do  auto f = [a, c] (double b) { return my_func(a, b, c);};?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a lambda function, as others have suggested, or `std::bind`. See how that will look and whether you like it better:

```
#include <functional>

double my_func(const double a, const double b)
{
    /* some arbitary function */ 
}

double solve_for_b_for_contant_a_by_bisection (const double a, 
                                               const double upperbound, 
                                               const double lowerbound)
{
    const auto f = std::bind(my_func, a, std::placeholders::_1);
             
    const auto lowerboundvalue = f(lowerbound);
    const auto upperboundvalue = f(upperbound);
    const auto midpointvalue = f(0.5 * (lowerbound+upperbound));
    /* The rest of the implementation */
}
```